# How to understand the phrase "of the trend" in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

The Headline is:

> if there is a ‘male Malaise’ with work, could one answer be at sea?
>
> Maritime transportation firms are desperate for new mariners, **a labor shortage that’s emblematic of the trend** for many male-heavy jobs in the trades.

the phrase: "a labor shortage that’s emblematic of the trend" was a little over my head to understand.

it was confusing for a learner mind. changing emblematic for symptomatic helped but raised more question. is the "trend" the author mention the job shortage?? if so then: "labor shortage that’s symptomatic of the trend" seems very overabundant.

can anybody says what it means in other words?

Comment: Have you tried to look up any of the words? Which don't you understand? However I think it's rather poor English. Rather than "emblematic" try "symptomatic" and see if it makes any more sense.

Comment: @Peter Jennings, it was confusing for a learner mind, or just my mind LOL changing emblematic for symptomatic helped but raised more question. is the "trend" the author mention the job shortage?? if so then: "labor shortage that’s symptomatic of the trend" seems very overabundant.

Comment: Yes I agree. Your quote is an example of the English rule "Never use lots and lots of unnecessary words or phrases when one or two would, most likely, be quite adequate." In other words "keep it simple".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from our exchange of comments.

> Maritime transportation firms are desperate for new mariners, a labor
> shortage that’s emblematic of the trend for many male-heavy jobs in
> the trades.

This is a bit difficult to put into simple terms, partly because the author is trying to express two ideas in one sentence. But I think it could be expressed as

> Ship owners are finding it difficult to recruit new sailors. There is
> a general shortage of job applicants in trades that employ mainly men.

However the original quote talks about "the trend" but fails (in the section quoted) to define just what trend they are talking about.

Comment: very nice answered. Thanks. I now can understand but let me ask you did you read the article to figure it out or did you just assume that as a possible answer? by your profile I see you're native english-speaker so I think you could infere this things without read the article.

Comment: @Lynerapintcho You are correct, I am a native British English (BrE) speaker. I don't know where your original article came from so I have not read it. I am used to people writing bad English, so I just figured it out from the fragment. If you like the answer, would you mind up-voting it please?

Comment: up-voted. pelase just one more thing, do you think for a better understanding of this headline I mean to convey a more acurate ideia of what the author mean could that be rewrite like:"a labor shortage that is emblematic FOR a trend THAT is for many male-heavy jobs in the trades."?? I belive now the author meant the "trend" to be Maritime firm jobs to be generally ocupied by men

Comment: @Lynerapintcho I still don't think that **emblematic** is the right word to use at all. If you look it up you find https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/emblematic defines it as a representation or symbol, like a sword being emblematic of power, or a flag being emblematic of a country.

Comment: @Lynerapintcho I'm sorry, but your revision still doesn't read right to me. It should be "emblematic **of** of a trend" not "**for** a trend".  "male-heavy" is another phrase I've never come across (brings up visions of big fat guys ), **male dominated** or **predominantly male** are far more common ways of saying it.  Perhaps you could say **"a labour (BrE spelling!) shortage that is emblematic of a trend in many predominantly male jobs in the trades."**. It's still an awkward way of putting it, but I think it means the same as the original even if I disagree with the choice of words.

Comment: it is like no matter how we change this text around, it doesn't make any clearer of what trends the author refers right?

Comment: any chance the meaning of this phrase " that’s emblematic of the trend" is the same as "that is an emblematic trend" so that would make: "a labor shortage that’s a trend which is emblematic for many male-heavy jobs in the trades." i would have started with this question but that idea wasn't clear for me.

Comment: to clarify what I'm thinking, that is the construction of "emblematic of the trend" is the same construction as "the hell of a job" isn't it?

Comment: @Lynerapintcho I hope that gotube's answer below covers your first two comments, and I'm afraid I'll have to leave your last comment to others as I'm not sure. I think we had better close these comments now as long discussions here are discouraged. I'm getting a message about it now!

Answer (score 1):

"a labor shortage that’s emblematic of the trend for many male-heavy jobs in the trades"

Here, "emblematic" could be replaced with "symbolic" or "representative".

So overall, the sentence means that the labour shortage in maritime transportation --a typically male industry-- is symbolic/representative of the problem of finding workers in typically male industries in general.

Comment: Thanks for helping me clarify the answer. I think the original quotation is badly written with a dubious choice of words.

Comment: @gotube, I finally got my head around it. also Peter Jennings's answer was very contributive. I would like to just focus on "representative of the trend". Is that the same as saying: "a trend that is representative"??

Comment: @Lynerapintcho No. The trend is *represent**ed***. "Representative" means "*represent**ing***".

Comment: @gotube, got it. But " emblematic of the trend" means same as "a trend that is emblematic" right?

Comment: @Lynerapintcho No. "X is emblematic of Y" means that X is emblematic, not Y. In this case, the trend is Y, so it's not representative or emblematic of anything.

Comment: @gotube, I fail to see exacly what the "trend" refers to. Would you say the trend refers to the labor shortage??? so labor shortage is a trend? it is a labor shortage's trend? if all truth I really fail to perceive how trend connect to "for many male-heavy jobs in the trades.". I'm sorry for spend so many time in the same question, it is a little confusing to me but also a foressen chalenge for a learing mind struggling to learn English

Comment: @gotube, should I read it like: "A trend for many male-heavy jobs in the trades."?? is that a right way to parse it?

Comment: @Lynerapintcho The trend is that many industries dominated by male labour -- most construction trades, landscaping, fishing, etc. -- are having trouble finding workers. The shortage of maritime transportation workers is one example of this trend. If X is an example of Y, then X can be representative of Y. So the shortage of maritime transportation workers is representative of the trend of male-dominated labour industries having trouble finding workers.